# R sf aggregate polygons at various geographic levels

Tags: r, sf

I'm trying to aggregate polygons at different geographic levels. As a hypothetical and reproducible example, let's suppose that I want to aggregate US county data set at the state level (of course, I can directly retrieve state-level polygons if this was my "actual" problem).

I've tried to do it by applying `st_union` for each group, where the group is each state. The code seems to work fine, but when I try to use it for plotting or other data manipulation, R throws an error message as below.

```
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : Not a matrix.
```

In general, if we have multiple levels of geography within a data (e.g., state, county, city, zip code, etc) and if we want to aggregate it at different levels, what's the best approach?

```
counties <- USAboundaries::us_counties() 

state_union <- counties %>% 
  group_by(state_abbr) %>%
  summarise(geometry = sf::st_union(geometry)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% st_as_sf()

plot(st_geometry(state_union))
```

Comment: I am experiencing this as well when using ` y %>%group_by(DN)%>%
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))` but only for certain files. Casting to multipolygon or polygon does not resolve this issue for me.

Comment: Actually, try this instead: `counties %>% 
  group_by(state_abbr) %>%summarize()`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Yea, indeed it has been discussed in Github (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/131).

Comment: Did that line of code solve the issue for you?

Comment: Yea it worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Instead try using this instead:

```
counties <- USAboundaries::us_counties() 

state_union <- counties %>% 
  group_by(state_abbr) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  ungroup() %>% st_as_sf()
```

Taking out the `union` statement seems to resolve the issue for me. I think it may be a bug.